# vb dll strange output in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

```vb
Module Module1
    Public Declare Function GET_CALCULATION_FAN_ALONE Lib "EbmPapstFan.dll" (ByRef path As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GET_PRODUCTS Lib "ebmpapstfan.dll" (ByRef path As String) As Long
    Public Declare Function SET_XML_PATH Lib "EbmPapstFan.dll" (ByRef path As String) As Long

    Sub Main()
        Dim Int_A As Long, Int_B As Long Str_Antwort As String, Str_Input As String
        Str_Input = "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\AppData\Local\ebmpapst\Product_selector_2011\Data\Fans\"
        Int_A = SET_XML_PATH(Str_Input)
        Int_B = GET_PRODUCTS("114709;A3G800AV0101;")

    End Sub

End Module
```

RESULTS

> Int_A = 12884901888 
>   Int_B = 25

How to rewrite this code in C# instead of VB?

```
[DllImport("EbmPapstFan.dll")]
public static extern long SET_XML_PATH(String path);

[DllImport("EbmPapstFan.dll")]
static extern long GET_CALCULATION_FAN_ALONE(String fanDescription);

[DllImport("EbmPapstFan.dll")]
public static extern long GET_PRODUCTS(String fanDescription);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long a = SET_XML_PATH(@"C:\Users\Sebastiaan\AppData\Local\ebmpapst\Product_selector_2011\Data\Fans\");
    long b = GET_PRODUCTS("114709;A3G800AV0101;");
}
```

RESULTS

> A = 579780113483169791  
>   B = 4294967292

i wrote this C# code but the output is not the same, how to solve this?

when i change long to int the resuls are a = -1 b = 4....

The dll is in Dephi, and should give the same output

Comment: How are the functions defined in the DLL?

Comment: Your strings are different between your vb and c#. `Fans` Vs `PlugFans_R-Typen`

Comment: I don't know, it's a dll written in Delphi. I could not open the dll because the file is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `string` parameters to `ref string`s (to match VB.Net's `ByRef`)

You will need to pass a `ref` string variable when calling the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If using 4.0, then u can try this. Not sure but might help. Use dynamic keyword.

```
dynamic comInterop= Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyCOM.Object.Name"));
var result = comInterop.MethodCall(parameter);
```