# VB - dll, string character output

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dllimport

I’m trying to obtain data from a dll, but I do not know how to do it.

My code is:

```vb
'Function
Public Declare Function SET_XML_PATH Lib "EbmPapstFan.dll" (ByRef ruta As String) As Long
Public Declare Function GET_PRODUCTS Lib "EbmPapstFan.dll" (ByRef ruta As String) As Long

Sub Selec()
        Dim ruta As String
        Dim Int_A As Long, Int_B

        ruta = "C:\ebmpapst\data\AC\"
        Int_A = SET_XML_PATH(ruta)  'If Int_A=0 then they aren't mistake

        Int_B = GET_PRODUCTS("")
        Worksheets("Selec").Range("E2").Value = Int_B   'Nº products
End sub
```

Results are:

```
Int_A= 0
Int_B= 18
```

This isn't a mistake with the path because Int_A is 0. In addition, GET_PRODUCTS gives me the number of products that software has.  The manual say that this function also has string character output.

The primary problem is that I don’t know how obtain this other string character output.

[vb dll strange output in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029721/vb-dll-strange-output-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Both outputs of the declared functions are "Long" and not "String" so there's no way that they're outputting anything except that.

I'd recommend revisiting the manual you refer to, to see exactly how it is documented and what the string value's function call would be.

Comment: the 'no way' part of that statement is not quite true, the parameter is byRef, it could returned with an adjusted value within it.

Comment: Then it's as easy as just str_Whatever = ruta right after the Int_A. Highly doubt that what she is talking about though, as you said, would need a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 function declaratons show `long` as the return types, however, the string being passed in is going in byRef and not byVal. It is possible that the string value is being returned via that parameter being adjusted inside the call.

More details about the documentation would be helpful.